# Beginner's guide to Facebook Apps

Tags: facebook

Can anybody point me to a good beginner's guide for making Facebook apps?

Comment: Make sure when you find a guide and look at it that it's recent, since they seem to change their interfaces every couple of months or so, and functions that were available on January are no longer available.

Comment: +1 Stupid Close Nazis strike again!  I found this question **very** helpful and constructive, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [facebook developer articles](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/)?

Comment: Isn't there a non facebook (external) source?

Comment: I would suggest you to do googling and read top results. Also the page http://www.softwaredeveloper.com/features/develop-facebook-app-072607/ contains some good links that you can follow.

Answer (score 1):

The [facebook developer forum](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=9074) is a good place to start as well.

Comment: The forum is read-only as of september 1, 2011. Users are redirected to http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1):

I brought the book, [Facebook Application Development for Dummies](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470768738). I am in the initial stages but does look like it explains the basics really well.

Comment: Yeah its really a very good book! Must try!

Comment: Thanks @VishwaKumar Have you tried any apps recently, I am looking to discuss more on the apps with some one who may have built one recently.